# Oracle Database 11gR2 Express Edition

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a problem with my server SQL as above. When I correct installed my OracleServiceXE I can't create the client after wrote the password from the installation as follow:

[image]

After installing the Oracle Database 11g Express Edition database server (during installation, you must
define an administrative password) create a new account for the user-owner of the test database.
For this purpose:

1. Run the Run SQL command line tool and log in to the system user account
   when entering an administrative password - the cursor does not move when entering the password (connect
   system) and I see above error. I think it is something with the port.

`C:\WINDOWS\system32>netstat -a`

Active Connections:

```
 Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State
  TCP    0.0.0.0:135            LAPTOP-45ATAF51:0      LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:445            LAPTOP-45ATAF51:0      LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:808            LAPTOP-45ATAF51:0      LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:1521           LAPTOP-45ATAF51:0      LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:5040           LAPTOP-45ATAF51:0      LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:6646           LAPTOP-45ATAF51:0      LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:7680           LAPTOP-45ATAF51:0      LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49664          LAPTOP-45ATAF51:0      LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49665          LAPTOP-45ATAF51:0      LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49666          LAPTOP-45ATAF51:0      LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49667          LAPTOP-45ATAF51:0      LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49668          LAPTOP-45ATAF51:0      LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49670          LAPTOP-45ATAF51:0      LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49675          LAPTOP-45ATAF51:0      LISTENING
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49731        LAPTOP-45ATAF51:0      LISTENING
  TCP    127.0.0.1:50245        LAPTOP-45ATAF51:0      LISTENING
  TCP    192.168.8.100:139      LAPTOP-45ATAF51:0      LISTENING
  TCP    192.168.8.100:49705    51.103.5.186:https     ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.8.100:49793    52.113.199.41:https    ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.8.100:49845    51.103.5.186:https     ESTABLISHED
```

Comment: Did you start the database up?

Answer (score 0):

`netstat` output isn't useful - you are trying to connect to a local instance without using the network.

You need to start up the database.

```
sqlplus / as sysdba
startup
```

If this fails then you should check the error message and the contents of your alert log.

Comment: Make sure ORACLE_SID is set correctly or this startup command won't work. Also, the OP is using Windows, so startup is better handled with starting the relevant Windows service rather than from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

Something appears to be listening on port 1521, which is good. It probably means that your database *is* started.

```
Proto Local Address Foreign Address State 
...
TCP 0.0.0.0:1521 LAPTOP-45ATAF51:0 LISTENING 
...
```

From the command prompt, you can confirm if the database is up and accepting connections by typing:

```
lsnrctl status
```

If you see the xe* services in the READY state then your database is up and running.

You can start all Oracle 11g XE services as described here (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17781_01/install.112/e18803/toc.htm#XEINW133) just to be sure.

Assuming that your database is up and running, before connecting from the sqlplus command line, make sure that your ORACLE_SID environment parameter is set to "XE" before connecting. For Windows:

```
> set ORACLE_SID=XE
> sqlplus /nolog
SQL> connect system
```

Comment: If `oracle_sid` wasn't set correctly, you would get `ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error` instead. The listener being active on port 1521 generally is not an indication of any database status.

Comment: ORA-12560 only pops up if you're actually using TNS. BEQ connections on localhost don't use TNS; connecting to a non-existant (or unset) ORACLE_SID value will result in exactly this error. You're right that the Listener being up isn't a guarantee that the database is also up, but it is a good sign that there wasn't some other problem with the installation, which is all I said.

Answer (score 0):

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>ORACLE_SID=orcl
'ORACLE_SID' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\WINDOWS\system32>set ORACLE_SID=XE

C:\WINDOWS\system32>sqlplus /nolog

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.2.0 Production on N Lut 28 13:33:08 2021

Copyright (c) 1982, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

SQL> SQL> connect system
SP2-0734: unknown command beginning "SQL> conne..." - rest of line ignored.
SQL> connect system
Enter password:
ERROR:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
ORA-27101: shared memory realm does not exist
Process ID: 0
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0
```

Thank you but it is the same result after wrote command to win.

Comment: It appears you _still_ have not started your database.  You have provided no evidence of having followed @Andrew Sayer advice about starting the database.